# How can I formalize the intuition behind this argument for the statement "every integer $n\geq 2$ is either prime or divisible by a prime"?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

During my recent journey exploring the world of elementary number theory, I conceived of an argument for the conclusion "every natural number $n\geq 2$ is either prime or divisible by a prime". As an added bonus, it also proves the validity of an intuitive prime factorization algorithm that’s taught in elementary schools and forms the basis of prime factorization trees. The argument goes like this:

> Fix an arbitrary natural number $n\geq 2$. If $n$ is prime (this can be tested with trial division), we're done.
>
> *
> If it isn't, then $n$ is composite, so there is a natural number $a_1\geq 2$ not equal to $n$ such that $n=a_1a_2$ for some natural number $a_2$.
>
> $a_1$ divides $n$ but does not equal $n$, so we must have $n>a_1$. Since $n=a_1a_2$ and $a_1\geq 2$, we can write
> \begin{align}
> n &= a_1a_2\\
> &= \underbrace{a_2+a_2+a_2+\cdots+a_2}_{\text{$a_1$ times}}\\
> &> a_2
> \end{align}
> and hence conclude that $n>a_2$. Moreover, since $a_1a_2\geq 2$ and $a_1\geq 2$, it must be the case that $a_2\geq 1$ (if $a_2<1$, then $a_2=0$, so $a_1a_2=0$). Notice that $a_2$ can't actually equal $1$ since this would imply that $n=a_1a_2=a_1$, contradicting the fact that $a_1\neq n$. Thus, $a_2\geq 2$.
>
> In summary, $n=a_1a_2$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are natural numbers satisfying $n>a_1\geq 2$ and $n>a_2\geq 2$.
> *
>
> If either $a_1$ or $a_2$ is prime, then we've found a prime that divides $n$, so we're done. If not, then they are both composite, so we can apply the logic bounded by the single asterisks to both $a_1$ and $a_2$ to deduce that $a_1=b_1b_2$ and $a_2=c_1c_2$ for natural numbers $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_1$, and $c_2$ satisfying $n>a_1>b_1\geq 2$, $n>a_1>b_2\geq 2$, $n>a_2>c_1\geq 2$, and $n>a_2>c_2\geq 2$
>
> If either $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_1$, or $c_2$ is prime, then we've found a prime that divides $n$. If not, then they're all composite, so we can apply the logic bounded by the asterisks to $b_1$, $b_2$, ...
>
> $\text{*the confusing section of the proof goes here*}$

Here's the core intuition behind why this “argument” works: if you ponder on the recursive process going on here, especially on the resulting inequalities

$$n>a_1>b_1>\cdots\geq 2$$
$$n>a_1>b_2>\cdots\geq 2$$
$$n>a_2>c_1>\cdots\geq 2$$
$$\vdots$$
it becomes evident that it must terminate after a finite number of steps. The numbers being produced by factoring the factors of $n$ are strictly decreasing and bounded below by $2$, so the process can't continue indefinitely because otherwise the numbers would eventually be less than $2$, contradicting the fact that they all have $2$ as a lower bound. My question is this: how I can formalize this intuition, particularly the vague phrases like “the numbers” and “factoring the factors of $n$”? Trying to use different letters/symbols to name all the numbers being produced is bound for failure ($n$ was given arbitrarily), so I instead tried to find a way to encode the numbers with distinct sequences like

$$(n, a_1, b_1, m_2, \dots)$$
$$(n, a_1, c_2, k_2, \dots)$$
$$\vdots$$

after which I would translate this intuition into the language of sequences. I don't think this will work though, since the number of sequences I’d need to account for every number will grow exponentially larger with larger and larger $n$; each of these sequences “bifurcates” when it reaches a composite number, so the number of sequences needed will double on average. More fundamentally, this doesn't seem like a catch-all approach that is independent of the size of $n$. Is there another way to encode the numbers being generated here? If not, what are some ways I can rigorously prove that this recursive process must terminate? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a nice [proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, see also the concept off infinite descent

Comment: @dxiv the proof by infinite descent isn’t glaring at me. Could you illustrate your idea in an answer? I’d like to have the chance to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

If such a number existed then you can construct a nonempty  subset of the natural numbers with no least bound but that contradicts the well ordering principle.

Comment: Hi Pax, thank you taking the time to answer! I’m having trouble following your logic. Specifically, what property/properties does the number you are referring to in “If such a number existed…” have? e.g. it’s a smallest divisor of n (this example is just to illustrate what I mean when I say “property”)

Comment: @AlannRosas If a number$\ge$2 (call it $y$) which is not divisible by any prime existed than it itself can't be prime but that means that it must have a divisor $x\ge2$ (which also can't be prime or divisible by a prime ) ,and $y>x$ now keep repeating the process and you will contradict the wo principle

Comment: @AlannRosas does that make sense?

Comment: sorry for the late rely! Your reasoning certainly shows that every natural number that is at least $2$ must be divisible by at least one prime; it even applies the process I described too! However, I’ve been thinking for a while and I can’t figure out why this either (1) formalizes the intuition I described toward the end of my post, or (2) offers a different way to prove that the algorithm must eventually terminate. Could you be kind enough to enlighten me? P.S. I apologize for having trouble seeing your logic. I sincerely don’t want to come across as a challenger.

Comment: @AlannRosas The process must terminate because if it doesn't then the well ordering principle would be false! My argument shows that if there is a number>2 not divisible by any prime than there is a subset of naturals which is not bounded below !

Comment: @AlannRosas consider the set of all divisors of $y$ except  1 can it have a lower bound?

Comment: the answer is yes if the process doesn’t terminate for $y$, which (as you mentioned) contradicts the well-ordering principle. But the addition of this second hypothesis, namely that the algorithm doesn’t terminate for $y$, makes me question whether the contradiction is immediately sufficient to prove that the algorithm must always terminate. It seems like your argument only implies that at least one of the two hypotheses, namely “there is a $y$ that is not divisible by any prime” and “the algorithm doesn’t terminate for $y$”, must be false. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: by the way, I greatly appreciate your willingness to work with me during this learning moment of mine.

Comment: @AlannRosas Why should the process terminate say a number>2  which is not divisible by any prime exists call it $x$ ,clearly it can’t be prime itself, now consider the set of all divisors of $x$ excluding one by WOP it must have a lower bound call it $y$ which also can’t be prime ,but that means….

Comment: $y$ also has a non one divisor  l such that $y>l$ but l is also a divisor of x contradicting y being the lower bound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128992/discussion-between-alann-rosas-and-pax-daga).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the OP's proof is valid.  Here is an alternative proof by induction.

The theorem is true for $n=2$.

Assume that the theorem is true for $\{2,3,\cdots, N\}.$

To prove: that the theorem is also true for $(N+1)$.

Without loss of generality, $(N+1)$ is not prime, else you are done.  Since it is not prime, it is composite.  This implies that there exists $a,b$ such that $(N+1) = ab,$ with $a < (N+1)$ and $b < (N+1)$.

Therefore $a|(N+1)~$ and $~a ~\in ~\{2,3,\cdots,N\}$.

By inductive assumption, either $a$ is prime or it is divisible by a prime $p$.

If $a$ is prime, then since $a|(N+1)$ the conjecture is proven for $(N+1)$.

Alternatively, if there is a prime $p$ such that $p|a$, then, since $a|(N+1)$, you have that $p|(N+1)$.  So again, the conjecture is proven for $(N+1)$.